# How to solve "Active: activating (auto-restart)" when starting collectd.service?

Tags: bash, systemd, fedora, collectd

I have problem with starting **collectd.serivce** in my Fedora 31 64-bit OS which I've installed via `sudo dnf install collectd` command. When I type `sudo systemctl status collectd.service` I get following output:

```sh
    ● collectd.service - statistics collection daemon
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/collectd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: activating (auto-restart) since Sat 2020-09-19 18:18:47 CEST; 3s ago
         Docs: man:collectd(1)
      Process: 3796 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/collectd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 3796 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CPU: 7ms
```

BTW, I've had to manually create `collectd.service` file which is located in */etc/systemd/system/* directory. What is really weird is I keep receiving **activating (auto-restart)** **status=0/SUCCESS** in above mentioned output. I also performed following commands in respective order:

1. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
2. `sudo systemctl stop collectd.service`
3. `sudo systemctl start collectd.service`

...but nothing changed and I've tried restarting my computer after all that and performing all mentioned 1)-3) steps and nothing helped.  BTW, this is my `collectd.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=statistics collection daemon
Documentation=man:collectd(1)
After=local-fs.target network.target
Requires=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/collectd
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is how my `/etc/collectd.conf` file looks like:

```
#
# Config file for collectd(1).
# Please read collectd.conf(5) for a list of options.
# http://collectd.org/
#

##############################################################################
# Global                                                                     #
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Global settings for the daemon.                                            #
##############################################################################

#Hostname    "localhost"
FQDNLookup   true
#BaseDir     "/var/lib/collectd"
#PIDFile     "/var/run/collectd.pid"
PluginDir   "/usr/lib64/collectd"
TypesDB     "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"

LoadPlugin cpu

<Plugin cpu>
  ReportByCpu false
  ReportByState false
#  Interval 1
  ValuesPercentage true
#  ReportNumCpu false
#  ReportGuestState false
#  SubtractGuestState true
</Plugin>

<Plugin memory>
        ValuesAbsolute false
        ValuesPercentage true
</Plugin>

Include "/etc/collectd.d"
LoadPlugin syslog
LoadPlugin logfile
#LoadPlugin log_logstash

<Plugin logfile>
        LogLevel info
        File "/var/log/error_syslog"
        Timestamp true
#       PrintSeverity false
</Plugin>

#<Plugin log_logstash>
#       LogLevel info
#       File "/var/log/collectd.json.log"
#</Plugin>

<Plugin syslog>
        LogLevel info
</Plugin>
Include "/etc/collectd.d"
```

**UPDATE1:**

Here is **output** of `/var/log/error_syslog` log file (set in `collectd.conf` file) that I get:

```
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] plugin_dispatch_values: No write callback has been registered. Please load at least one output plugin, if you want the collected data to be stored.
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status 2 (ENOENT). Most likely this means you didn't load any write plugins.
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:25] collectd: Stopping 5 write threads.
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] plugin_load: plugin "cpu" successfully loaded.
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] plugin_load: plugin "memory" successfully loaded.
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Initialization complete, entering read-loop.
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Exiting normally.
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] plugin_dispatch_values: No write callback has been registered. Please load at least one output plugin, if you want the collected data to be stored.
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] collectd: Stopping 5 read threads.
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status 2 (ENOENT). Most likely this means you didn't load any write plugins.
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] Available write targets:: [none]
[2020-09-20 11:04:35] collectd: Stopping 5 write threads.
```

Any suggestion/pointing me in right direction how to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check collectd's own log to find out why it is exiting.

Comment: Hi Michael, is there any specific command for doing that? Also, where should it (log) be (usually) located? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The log ought to be where you specified it in the configuration file you posted.

Comment: Michael, I've updated my question with **UPDATE1** section which contains output of collectd's log file. Please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After "experimenting" I managed to reach a solution and make collectd.service run by editing `ExecStart` property in my `/etc/systemd/system/collectd.service` file by setting following value:

`ExecStart=/usr/sbin/collectd -C /etc/collectd.conf -f`

...found at this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martin-magakian/collectd-script/master/collectd.service).

Hope that helps if someone gets in this kind of situation. :)
Cheers!